# AR(k)-GARCH(1,1) model. Why am I getting same Log-likelihoods and AICs?

Tags: python, garch, pandas

I am trying to for loop an AR(k)-GARCH(1,1) model, however it seems that I am getting same log-likelihoods and AICs. I believe that my code is fine, since I manually checked the iterations. Is there any statistically theoretical reason why is this happening?

```
garch_models = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AIC','Log-Likelihood'],index=garch_columns)
for i in np.arange(len(garch_models)):
    AEX_GARCH_0 = arch_model(log_r['AEX'], lags=i, vol='Garch', p=1, o=0, q=1, dist='t')
    res_AEX = AEX_GARCH_0.fit()
    res_AEX.summary()
    garch_models.iloc[i,0]= res_AEX.aic
    garch_models.iloc[i,1]= res_AEX.loglikelihood
```

Here's what I am getting in the data frame:
[image]

Here are two of the iterations (so I can save some space):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add mean = 'AR' ([see documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/arch/latest/arch.pdf)):

```
arch_model(log_r['AEX'], mean='AR', lags=i, vol='Garch', p=1, o=0, q=1, dist='t')
```

Try to check the model specification of AEX_GARCH_0 for the different iterations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how I didn't see this before.... silly me

Comment: No problem. Sometimes we just miss something. Please accept the answer :)